# React, using .map with index

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple React component like so:

```
import React from 'react';

const ListPage = ({todos}) => (
  <div>
    <h6>todos</h6>
    <ul>
    {todos.map(({todo, index}) => (
      <li key={index}>{todo}</li>
    ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
)

ListPage.propTypes = {
  todos: React.PropTypes.array,
};

export default ListPage;
```

I can see that the docs for [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) shows that the second argument is index, next to currentValue. How does one alter the existing code to pick up the second argument?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You need to to this:

`todos.map((key, index) => { ... })` without object brackets for arguments.

`({todo, index}) => { ... }` - that syntax means that you want to get properties `todo` and `index` from first argument of function.

You can see syntax [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

Basic syntax

```
 (param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements }
 (param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
          // equivalent to:  => { return expression; }

 // Parentheses are optional when there's only one parameter:
 (singleParam) => { statements }
 singleParam => { statements }

 // A function with no parameters requires parentheses:
 () => { statements }
```

Advanced syntax

```
 // Parenthesize the body to return an object literal expression:
 params => ({foo: bar})

 // Rest parameters and default parameters are supported
 (param1, param2, ...rest) => { statements }
 (param1 = defaultValue1, param2, …, paramN = defaultValueN) => { statements }

 // Destructuring within the parameter list is also supported
 var f = ([a, b] = [1, 2], {x: c} = {x: a + b}) => a + b + c;
 f();  // 6
```

Answer (score 22):

Here is an example based on Timur Bilalov's answer to make easy to understand.

```
var materials = [
  'Hydrogen',
  'Helium',
  'Lithium',
  'Beryllium'
];

materials.map((material,index) => console.log(index +" = " + material + " = " + materials[index]));
```

**Output**

```
"0 = Hydrogen = Hydrogen"
"1 = Helium = Helium"
"2 = Lithium = Lithium"
"3 = Beryllium = Beryllium"
```

**Reference**
https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Hope it help

Answer (score 15):

Be careful, you should not use the index as a key if the list is dynamic, it is [antipattern](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318#.6nz2tbgsw) and could lead into troubles.

You should use the index as a key ONLY if you are sure you will not have to delete or add items to your todos after creation (it could still be acceptable if you add items but only at the end of the list, and still never delete). Otherwise React might run into problems reconciliating your children.

The best practise is to add an "id" to all your todos (incremental or UUID) and use it as the key for all the react lists that need it.

Comment: While my goal is to use a _id provided from Mongo, to test the function out, I realized I needed to understand the way es6 .map works first.

Comment: I get your point. FYI, map is not ES6 specific, but arrow functions are. You can use .map in all browser since IE9 a long time ago.